# How to make array dynamic in ReactJS?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, dynamic

I want to make my table row dynamic so it can automatically add new data from the MySQL database but I don't know how. Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

Here is my static data that I wanted to make dynamic. Im having error whenever I put 'campusValues.map'. It gives me a message of '',' expected'.

```
const data = {
rows: [
  {
  Campus_name: 'National Arabella SHS',
  tel_number: ' 123-12-123',
  action: 
  <div className='action-icon-container'>
      <Tooltip title="Edit" trigger="hover">
          <Link to='/admin/campus/edit-campus/:id' state={{bc_edit_type : 1}}><MdEdit className='action-icon edit' /></Link>
      </Tooltip>
  </div> 
 },
 {
 Campus_name: 'College of Arabella - Main',
 tel_number: ' 123-12-123',
 action: 
 <div className='action-icon-container'>
    <Tooltip title="Edit" trigger="hover">
        <MdEdit className='action-icon edit' />
    </Tooltip>
</div> 
},
{
 Campus_name: 'College of Arabella Extension',
tel_number: ' 123-12-123',
action:
<div className='action-icon-container'>
    <Tooltip title="Edit" trigger="hover">
        <MdEdit className='action-icon edit' />
    </Tooltip>
</div> 
 },
 ]

 };
```

Here is the part where I get the data from the database and store it in 'campusValues' variable.

```
const CampusPage = () => {

const [campusValues, setCampusValues] = useState([]);

const GetCampusValues = () => {
   Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/campusValues").then((response) => {
     console.log(response);
     setCampusValues(response.data);
 });
}

 useEffect(() => {
   let ignore = false;
   if (!ignore)  
   GetCampusValues();
   return () => { ignore = true; }
 },[]);

 return (...);
 }

 export default CampusPage
```

Comment: Maybe you need to update `campusValues` by `setCampusValues(response.data.rows)`

Comment: I want to replace the values from rows with the data from MySQL that's why I used Axios. I can fetch the data from MySQL but my problem is I cannot replace it with rows' values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by trying this code below. :)

```
  rows : campusValues?.map((val, key) => {
            return {
                Campus_name: `${val.campus_description}`,
                tel_number: `${val.campus_telephone_number}`,
                campus_head: `${val.campus_head}`,
                action: 
                <div className='action-icon-container'>
                    <Tooltip title="Edit" trigger="hover">
                        <Link to='/admin/campus/edit-campus/:id' state={{bc_edit_type : 1}}><MdEdit className='action-icon edit' /></Link>
                    </Tooltip>
                </div> 
            }
        })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).